# Javascript : Set the href attribute of an image map area

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How can I address an existing image map area in JS, to set its href property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like anything else:

```
document.getElementById('areaId').href=newLink;
```

Comment: Thanks. Somehow I thought I remembered ID attribute wasn't supported by image areas, and we needed to iterate through and test all areas =)